# How should I write units?

Tags: punctuation, measuring-units

In a scientific article, should I write "3m", "3 m", "3 meters", or "3 [meters]"?

Comment: None of the above - go with **3 m** (using a *thin space* between number and unit).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This guide](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html) at the NIST site is a good place to start.

In particular, you should write "3 m" as in "The bar is 3 m long."

Comment: I've edited the answer to answer the particular question (feel free to revert if necessary), but yes, the guide is great as a reference for all unit issues.

Answer (score 11):

The abbreviation for *meter* is *m*; it is not written between brackets, and you need to add a space between the value and the measuring unit.

The absence of brackets, and the presence of a space to separate the measuring unit from the numeric value is not limited to *meter*, but it is common for all the measuring units.

Answer (score 10):

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si_units#Unit_symbols_and_the_values_of_quantities):

> The value of a quantity is written as a number followed by a space (representing a multiplication sign) and a unit symbol; e.g., "2.21 kg", "7.3×102
>    m<sup>2</sup>", "22 K".
>
> This rule explicitly includes the percent sign (%). Exceptions are the symbols for plane angular degrees, minutes and seconds (°, ′ and ″), which are placed immediately after the number with no intervening space.

So three meters should be written as **3 m**.